# Safari undoes media queries

Tags: css, safari, responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-safari

I'm working on a responsive design for tablet-smartphone range.

Here is the media query I'm using for this range of device:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    header nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

All this one does is hide the navigation bar list if the screen width is between 300-999px.

This works fine on Chrome, but on Safari, the page initially loads taking the media queries into account. A few seconds after the page has loaded, the media queries are cancelled out and the page reverts to it's default layout.

The same happens on my iPhone Safari. Media queries work fine on Chrome (on Desktop and Android)

**How can I make sure my media queries are *always* enforced on Safari (desktop/iPhone)?**

[You can see the page here for yourself](http://rlcoaching.com/newrl)

EDIT:

I've added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;">
```

This doesn't solve the problem. It helps with the zoom but the nav bar still pops back in when page completely loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting some very weird results in Safari, where your media queries can't override the main classes even though you load them afterwards.

I have only tried this in dev tools but by going up a step in the DOM tree it seems to force your media queries to behave properly.

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    body header nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't tried this on desktop Safari. Thanks for pointing out that the problem is with Safari in general, not just on my iPhone. I gave it a try by going up in the DOM. It is not working. I get the same weird behavior where the page is loaded taking into account the media-queries and then after a few seconds reverts back to the default layout.

Comment: Thanks, it does work by going up in the DOM. For some reason I think it has something to do with Safari doing a popstate after page load (something that other browsers don't do)

Comment: That could be it. I've never experienced that exact issue and it is indeed quite weird.

Comment: Can you mark this as resolved if the issue no longer persists please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 300px) 
and (max-device-width : 999px) 
{ /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

I think it help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't help. On my iPhone it had the exact same effect as my previous code, and it also stops working on desktop like that.